# org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed error when running groovy script

Tags: grails, groovy

I am trying to run a groovy script from command prompt

```
C:\devl\rads-mfsfp-3762-batch\mfr>C:\devl\rads-mfsfp-3762-batch\mfr\bin\run_script.bat TestScript
```

and I am getting this error

```
MFR_DRIVER_CLASS: Mfr
MFR_BATCH_CLASS: TestScript
MFR_CMD_LINE_ARGS:
INFO   - Executing script: TestScript.groovy, null
INFO   - STARTED AT: 10/19/2018 14:05:16.484
Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed, script1539972317344.groovy: 1: expecting '!', found 'U' @ line 1, column 2.
1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:296)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addFatalError(ErrorCollector.java:143)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.addError(SourceUnit.java:352)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:80)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:248)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:143)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:772)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:438)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:277)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:248)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:243)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:205)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:215)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:86)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:230)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:912)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:946)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:756)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePojoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:766)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:754)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:170)
    at groovy.util.ConfigSlurper.parse(ConfigSlurper.groovy:151)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:86)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:230)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:912)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:946)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:756)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:778)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:758)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:170)
    at DBConnectionUtil.readBatchDataSourceConfig(DBConnectionUtil.groovy:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:86)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:230)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:912)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:946)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:756)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:778)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:758)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:170)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethod0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:198)
    at GormHelper.loadProperties(GormHelper.groovy:122)
    at GormHelper.this$2$loadProperties(GormHelper.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:86)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:230)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:912)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnCurrentN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:78)
    at GormHelper.buildConfiguration(GormHelper.groovy:109)
    at GormHelper.this$2$buildConfiguration(GormHelper.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:86)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:230)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:912)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnCurrentN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:78)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnCurrent0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:112)
    at GormHelper.doInitialize(GormHelper.groovy:67)
    at GormHelper.this$2$doInitialize(GormHelper.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:86)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:230)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:912)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:756)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:778)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:758)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:170)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethod0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:198)
    at GormHelper.initialize(GormHelper.groovy:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:86)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:230)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1105)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:749)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:170)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethod0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:198)
    at Mfr.main(Mfr.groovy:35)
Finished executing TestScript. Please check for errors.

This is the TestScript groovy script

class TestScript {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        println "Hello World"
    }

}
```

How can I find out what the issue is? I am using a very old version of grails 1.0.3 and jdk 1.7. Grails home and Groovy home are setup properly.

Comment: the actual error: `script1539972317344.groovy: 1: expecting '!', found 'U' @ line 1, column 2.`. you run `run_script.bat` that is not a standard way to run groovy script. check what's inside of  `run_script.bat`

Comment: Could you show the source code of `Mfr.groovy` file, and highlight 35 line?